# Proof of the Weierstrass corollary.

Tags: optimal-control

I need help with the proof of this corollary of the Weierstrass theorem:

Let *X* $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set and *f* : $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ an inferiorly continuous function that verifies $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}$ *f(x)* = + $\infty$. Hence it exists a  $\hat{x}$ $\in$ *X* where *f* ($\hat{x}$) $\leq$ *f (x)* $\forall$ *x* $\in$ *X*.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. For example $f(x)=x$ is continuous but if  $K=(0,1)$ then its infimum is not attained.

However this is true if $K$ is also closed.  If $m=\inf_x f(x)$. There exists a sequence $x_n $ such that $f(x_n) \to m$. Since $x_n$ is bounded there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Let its limit be $\hat {x}$.  By lower semi-continuity we get $f(\hat x) \leq \lim f(x_{n_k})=m$. But $m \leq f(x)$ for all $x$ so we are done.

Comment: I should've written "closed" too! Thank you so much!